# Buying laptops - Which ones would be easier to dual boot?

Tags: laptop, intel

I am looking for a laptop with the following specs - 16 GB RAM/Intel core i7 11th gen (8 cores)/4 GB NVidia RTX 3050 (or better) Graphics Card.
I have shortlisted

`Acer Predator Helios 300 Core i7 11th Gen - (16 GB/1 TB HDD/512 GB SSD/Windows 10 Home/4 GB Graphics/NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050ti/165 Hz) PH315-54 Gaming Laptop  (15.6 inch, Abyssal Black, 2.3 kg)`

`MSI Katana GF66 Core i7 11th Gen - (16 GB/1 TB SSD/Windows 10 Home/4 GB Graphics/NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050/144 Hz) Katana GF66 11UC-628IN Gaming Laptop (15.6 inches, Black, 2.25 kg)`

I want a laptop on which I would be able to **easily set up a dual boot** with Ubuntu or Kali Linux. I know there are some issues with dual booting laptops that have Intel RST (Rapid storage Technology) on.

So please suggest a laptop with similar specs or tell me which one of the two I have shortlisted would be easier to dual boot?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the top one

For dualboot, you need a lot of storage, and since the top one has more, go with that. Also, the top one has a better gpu (although AMDGPU's play  better with linux). I don't know how well the biosses are running on those laptops for dualboot (old Acer laptops do have a good bios) but do turn Secure Boot off if you are running linux.